# Connecting C# to a Named Pipe from Hyper-V Permissions

Tags: c#, named-pipes, hyper-v

I'm trying to write a very simple client in c# for a named pipe created by hyper-v on windows 8 pro.

The hyper-v named pipe is connected to the com port of a virtual machine.

The code i have written is:

```
    static void PipeClient()
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream npc = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "DebianCom1", PipeDirection.InOut);
        npc.Connect();
        var s = new StreamReader(npc);
        var cont = true;
        while (cont)
        {
            Console.Write(s.Read());
        }
        s.Close();
        npc.Close();
    }
```

It throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException on the instantiation of the named pipe client.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try running your C# code as an elevated admin.

Comment: think i tried that already, but i'll check again tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Also, is it not possible to set a permission for my user to use the named pipes without elevation?